# When posting Json using jQuery posted data is different than payload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can any one tell me why, when I construct a string in Jquery, in the Chrome Javascript Debugger it shows like:

```
{"ClaimType":"Trade","ClaimedProductId":4,"ClaimingUserId":3,"Message":"","TradeOffers":"[{"OfferedProductId":"3","OfferedQuantity":"2"},{"OfferedProductId":"3","OfferedQuantity":"5234"}]"}
```

But when I post it using $.ajax and then check the POST request's payload in the Chrome Debugger, it looks like:

```
{"ClaimType":"Trade","ClaimedProductId":4,"ClaimingUserId":3,"Message":"","TradeOffers":"[{\"OfferedProductId\":\"3\",\"OfferedQuantity\":\"2\"},{\"OfferedProductId\":\"3\",\"OfferedQuantity\":\"5234\"}]"}
```

Those backslashes aren't supposted to be there, correct? When I test my MVC 4 controller action with the Rest Console (no slashes) all works fine.

Somewhere things are not going the way they are supposed to. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have the `"` just before the `[` and after `]`?

Comment: Due to the way you're structuring your json, yes, the backslashes are supposed to be there. What you have is json inside of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it guys :-)

Thanks for putting me on the right track pointing out the fact that I was passing a string instead of an array.

After some more research I just fixed it inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812927/how-to-create-json-obj-or-array-from-divs-ids) and finally creating this code:

```
    var productOffers = $("div.tradeOffer").map(function () {
    var productOffer = { OfferedProductId: $(this).find(".selectTraderOffer:selected").val(), OfferedQuantity: $(this).find(".tradeProductQuantity").val() };
    return productOffer;
}).get();
return productOffers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at this part:

```
TradeOffers":"[{"OfferedProductId
```

That quotation mark just after the colon tells me that TradeOffers' value is actually a string, which happens to contain a JSON array. Chrome is just making sure that it will come out the other side as a string, complete with any quotation marks in it.

You'll just need to find where TradeOffers is set, and if there's something wrong with it. Funny enough, this sort of issue seems to be common lately...

Comment: Yep, Katana314 is right. Is the value of TradeOffers an array of objects, or a string representation of such a thing?

Comment: Thanks guys for your input! Yes, the value op TradeOffers is an array of objects. It's not supposted to be a string representation! :-). I am fairly new to JSON and curious what does it take to to fix this? Remove the the quotation mark before `[{"OfferedProductId`? FYI - I am posting to a MVC 4 controller action which execpts a view model which deserializes the incoming request. [Please look at a previous question regaring this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701669/posting-json-to-mvc-4-webapi-controller-action-why-doesnt-it-deserialize-my-ar)

Comment: @MetaVerse Well, if you're hand-writing JSON, the solution is easy. Remove the mentioned quotation mark and the very final one, then remove the slashes on the other quotes inside it. But I'm guessing it's being generated by either your Javascript, or some other program. In that case, you need to find where it's converting the TradeOffers array into JSON; at some point, it seems to do an unnecessary 'JSON.stringify' too early.